# Kafka event is getting retried even though Retry mechanism is absent

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

```
    @Bean
      public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> dcmContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(**consumerEventFactory()**);
        Map<String, String> micrometerTags = new HashMap<>();
        micrometerTags.put(KafkaCommonConfig.CONSUMER_TAG, TAG_VALUE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setMicrometerTags(micrometerTags);
        return factory;
      }
```

**consumerEventFactory()** in the above is called from below :

```
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerEventFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getBootStrapServers());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "randommmmm");
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getMaxPollIntervalMs());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getMaxPollRecords());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getRequestTimeOutMs());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getHeartbeatIntervalMs());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,
        "true");
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
        CCMReader.getCcmDcmConsumerConfig().getAutoCommitIntervalMs());
    config.put(
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
        "earliest");
    config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        config, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
  }
```

Since there is no error handler, all the exceptions should be rejected.
However, the exception events are being called again and again (infinite times)
Not sure what is happening...only conclusion till now is black magic. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening when the exception occurs? Is the consumer process getting restarted?

`Since there is no error handler, all the exceptions should be rejected.`- No I don't think so.

Its normal for Kafka consumer to exit when exception is not handled within process method. So once the consumer comes up again (restart policy of your docker may be), it starts reading the same events since those events are not yet committed back to brokers from this client id as successful.

Am not sure of Spring Kafka, but I feels like you should define exception handling to make sure that those events are handled properly so that they are committed back as normal events than killing the consumer and running into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is no error handler,...

The default error handler (2.8 and later) is the `DefaultErrorHandler` (`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` for earlier versions).

Both these error handlers will retry 9 times.